# javascript code with php not working

Tags: javascript

This is my code-
[javascript function caldate starts here-]

```
var selected = obj.value;
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var mon = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; var month;
if(mon<10)
    month="0"+mon;
else month=mon;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var thed=year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
if(selected===thed){
    var t=currentDate.getHours()+1;    
}
else 
    var t=9;

if(currentDate.getDay()==6){
    var t1=12;
}
else
    var t1=17;

var i=0;
document.getElementById("dtime").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("dtime").innerHTML="<select>";
for(i=t;i<t1;i++)
    document.getElementById("dtime").innerHTML+="<option>"+i+"</option>";

document.getElementById("dtime").innerHTML+="</select>";
```

[javascript caldate function ends here]

Select Date: `<input type="date" id="appdate" onchange="caldate(this)"><br>
<div id="dtime"></div>`

I call fucntion caldate from here after onchange event on calendar
Div dtime is here..where I want to display the time dropdown

So..alerts and all are being printed in javascript..but the select is not being displayed..I just see an empty dropdown list

Comment: Share your HTML also.

Comment: Where's the PHP part?

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP ?

Comment: Yeah, don't paste that in the comments, edit your question and paste it there please. Thx

Comment: @Zyigh ...my bad..php was not required..Can u please atleast help me with the javascript

Comment: @kerbholz I added the html part..there is no php yet

Comment: Make a function that creates an element with tag, parent, and textContent as argument (such as `function htmlCreator(tag, parent, textContent)`. This function create the html node, put it textContent if it exists, and attach it to the parent. Then it returns the node. You'd have something like `var select = htmlCreator('select', document.getElementById('dtime'));
    for (var i = 0; i < t1; i++) { htmlCreator('option', select, String(i)); }`. Look at node.appendChild() and document.createElement(). It will be easier for you to work with a structured code where logic blocks are isolated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was make 2 different ids...

document.getElementById("dtime").innerHTML=" &lt select id='t2' &gt"; 
for(i=t;i<t1;i++)
    document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML+=" &lt option &gt"+i+"&lt /option &gt";

document.getElementById("dtime").innerHTML+="&lt /select &gt";